# Finding condition s.t the limit of a multivariable function exists at a point.

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

> Let $f(x,y)=\dfrac{x^{\alpha}}{1-2y\cos x+y^2}$ $(\alpha>0, x>0, y\in\mathbb{R}).$
> a) Find the domain of $f(x,y)$.
> b) Find all values of $\alpha$ s.t $f$ has limit at $(0,1)$ and find that limit.

My attempt:
a) $\left[\begin{matrix}
x\neq k\pi (k\in\mathbb{N}^*), x>0, y\in\mathbb{R}.\\
x=k\pi (k\in\mathbb{N}^*), y\neq \pm 1.\\
\end{matrix}\right.$

b) Notice that $\lim\limits_{(0,y)\to (0,1)} f(x,y)=0$ and $\lim\limits_{(x,1)\to (0,1)} f(x,y)=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}x^{\alpha-2}$. So, if $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,1)}f(x,y)$ exists $\Rightarrow\alpha>2$.\

Conversely, if $\alpha>2$, I don't know how to prove $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,1)}f(x,y)=0$.

Could anyone give me hints?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

By $u=x$ and $v=y-1$ we have

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,1)}\dfrac{x^{\alpha}}{1-2y\cos x+y^2}=\lim_{(u,v)\to (0,0)}\dfrac{u^{\alpha}}{v^2+2v-2(v+1)\cos u+2}$$

with $\cos u = 1-\frac{u^2}2+o(u^2)$ that is

$$\lim_{(u,v)\to (0,0)}\dfrac{u^{\alpha}}{v^2+u^2+o(u^2)}$$

which requires $\alpha >2$ in order to have $0$ as limit.

---

As an alternative, for $\alpha >2$

$$\dfrac{u^{\alpha}}{v^2+2v-2(v+1)\cos u+2}=\dfrac{u^{\alpha}}{v^2+2(v+1)(1-\cos u)}=$$

$$=\dfrac{u^{\alpha-2}}{\frac{v^2}{u^2}+2(v+1)\frac{1-\cos u}{u^2}}\le \dfrac{u^{\alpha-2}}{2(v+1)\frac{1-\cos u}{u^2}}\to \frac 0 1=0 $$